# using regex with group by in Apache spark

Tags: string, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables first one contains the car model, and second one contains specific mode of that model

for example :

This is a part of first table :

> Car Brand:
>
> Abarth
>
> Alfa Romeo
>
> Aston Martin
>
> Audi
>
> Bentley
>
> BMW

and second table  :

> Make/Model:
>
> Chevrolet Pickup (Full Size)
>
> Ford Pickup (Full Size)
>
> Toyota Camry
>
> Nissan Altima
>
> Chevrolet Impala
>
> Honda Accord
>
> GMC Pickup (Full Size)

and I need to join these two tables, I need to use regex on it so i can take the first part of the second table and join the two tables

for example :

**> Honda Accord join with Honda in first table**

I did something like this :

```
Dataset<Row> updatedCars = carsTable.join(carsTheftsTable, expr("Car Brand rlike Make/Model")).cache();
```

but it's not working in java spark `expr` not found

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to cross join and check each model with each car brand if they fit.

For example in `pyspark`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F  # noqa
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ["Honda"],
    ["Alfa Romeo"],
    ["Aston Martin"],
    ["Toyota"],
    ["Nissan"],
    ["BMW"]
], schema=StructType([StructField("car_brand", StringType())])).cache()

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    ["Chevrolet Pickup (Full Size)"],
    ["Ford Pickup (Full Size)"],
    ["Toyota Camry"],
    ["Nissan Altima"],
    ["Chevrolet Impala"],
    ["Honda Accord"],
    ["GMC Pickup (Full Size)"]
], schema=StructType([StructField("car_model", StringType())])).cache()

df1.crossJoin(df2).filter(F.col("car_model").contains(F.col("car_brand"))).show(100, False)

+---------+-------------+                                                       
|car_brand|car_model    |
+---------+-------------+
|Honda    |Honda Accord |
|Toyota   |Toyota Camry |
|Nissan   |Nissan Altima|
+---------+-------------+
```